# What files can be cleared in RT_* folders on datastage server?

Tags: datastage

I am facing space crunch because there are a million files under my RT_* folders. For example: RT_SCxxx,RT_BPxxx,DS_TEMPxxx,RT_LOGxxx directories.

Can i delete the files under these directories, if yes how to be sure that which files can be deleted so my Jobs are not getting corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

ibm doesn't provide any Kind of housekeeping.

Here are some ressources on files you can delete:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21578601
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.admin.nav.doc/containers/c_manage_filesys.html

We also delete *.tmp and *.err files, and wie empty our Scratch folder after wie shut down the Server.

Hope this helps.